# Alterar link de botão de acordo com um select

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou desenvolvendo uma tabela de planos, onde os valores destes planos variam conforme as opções selecionadas no  (são 4 opções de seleção).

Esta parte de alterar o valor do plano conforme as opções escolhidas já foi resolvida, no entanto, os botões de "ADERIR" aos planos, não variam conforme as opções selecionadas. (estes links irão direcionar para a compra deste plano de assinatura, como cada combinação das opções selecionadas é um valor, gostaria que os links dos botões variassem também conforme as opções selecionadas.)

Segue o link da tabela:
https://piscinafacil.com.br/tabela_teste.html#

Comment: Você quer alterar somente o link de acordo com cada tabela e suas respectivas informações? Se entendi corretamente basta gerar o link completo no js e imprimir junto do HTML.

Comment: Isso @LucasThibauPaulino , ia ser um link diferente para cada combinação das 4 opções do select.

Como não tenho muita experiência com js, gostaria de pedir sua ajuda para estruturar essa parte do js. Pois o js que já está na tabela foi feito por uma outra pessoa, eu só desenvolvi a parte do html e css mesmo.

Se puder me ajudar, ficarei extremamente agradecido, pois só falta isso para finalizar a tabela. Obrigado!

Comment: @LucasThibauPaulino Vi que você tinha postado uma resposta, mas foi excluída... Consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Básicamente você vai montar um array com as opções que estão sendo enviadas pra montar a tabela, a partir desse array, você concatena tudo e gera o link. Pra saber como fazer isso exatamente, é necessário ver seu código.

Comment: @LucasThibauPaulino Certo Lucas, não estava conseguindo postar o código inteiro aqui. Mas se você entrar no link que está a tabela conseguirá exibir o código fonte dela.

O outro rapaz que respondeu a pergunta já postou um exemplo de como seria o código, porém o link só muda quando uma opção é selecionada. Já no meu caso, o link teria que mudar quando um conjunto de opções é selecionada. Mais uma vez obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: A resposta do @Leandro Silva foi correta e serve para resolver seu problema, a questão é que, ao invés de somente um if você irá ter vários if e concatenar os resultados de cada if para no fim gerar uma url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para alterar o link de acordo com a opção selecionada, você poderia fazer de diversas formas, entre elas, a forma mostrada abaixo. 
Peguei o campo de volume como exemplo para demonstrar como fazer:

```js
   jQuery(function($){
        $('#volume, #visitas').change(function(){
  var volume = $('#volume').val();
  var visitas = $('#visitas').val();
  if (volume == "50" && visitas == "4") {
             $('.Linkbotao').attr('href', 'http://www.google.com.br');
  }
  else if (volume == "80" && visitas == "4") {
      $('.Linkbotao').attr('href', 'http://www.uol.com.br');
  }
  else if (volume == "50" && visitas == "8") {
      $('.Linkbotao').attr('href', 'http://www.yahoo.com.br');
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<form>
     Volume <select name="volume" id="volume">
 <option value="" selected>Selecione</option>
 <option value="50">50</option>
 <option value="80">80</option>
     </select>
     <br>
     <br>
     Visitas <select name="visitas" id="visitas">
     <option value="" selected>Selecione</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="8">8</option>
     </select>
     <br>
     <br>
     <a href="#" class="Linkbotao" target="_blank">
       <input type="button" name="aderir" id="aderir" value="aderir"> 
     </a>
</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @LeandroSilva. Como sou leigo em javascript, queria te pedir a ajuda de como fazer a combinação de mais de um select gerar um link, e outra combinação, gerar outro link.

Por exemplo: Existem dois selects: Volume(50 ou 80) e Visitas(4 ou 8)
1 combinação: Volume [50] + Visitas [4] = google.com.br
2 combinaçao: Volume [80] + Visitas [4] = uol.com.br
3 combinação: Volume [50] + Visitas [8] = yahoo.com
E assim por diante. Pois nessa tabela que estou criando, os links seriam gerados mediante a combinação de diversos selects, e não somente um select.

Comment: @Eduardo Marotti Editei o post para o caso em questão, coloquei os dois selects como informado e as combinações com os respectivos links.

Comment: Show de bola mano, muito obrigado mesmo! Vou tentar adaptar agora às opções lá da minha tabela. Qualquer coisa volto aqui para perguntar. :)

Comment: Seguinte, tenho uma dúvida referente à um select da minha tabela. O select "estado" e "cidade" eles não são definidos no html,  e sim "puxados" do banco de dados. Por exemplo, a cidade São Paulo, só irá aparecer quando o estado SP for selecionado. E estes não aparecem no select, portanto não sei indicar o value de cada cidade. É possível utilizar estes dados, de estado e cidade, para gerar o Linkbotao?

Comment: São muitas opções de cidades e estados? Caso não sejam muitas opções dá para fazer nesse modo IF, else if mesmo, porém na hora da verificação você teria que colocar o valor idêntico ao retornado do banco. Ex.: if (volume == "50" && visitas == "4" && estado == "SP" && cidade == "São Paulo"){ 
Se for muitas opções de cidades e estados, teria que esperar ver se a galera mais experiente aqui tem alguma ideia, pois nunca fiz isso com JS.

Comment: Então @LeandroSilva São poucas cidades, tentei fazer dessa maneira e não ta dando certo. Será que é por que o "value"(no caso o nome da cidade) não está nas options do select? E sim no banco de dados? De qualquer maneira, muito grato pela ajuda até o momento. Estamos quase lá. Hahah