# Como descobrir o value de um <select> que é puxado do banco de dados

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou montando uma tabela de planos [TABELA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206567/alterar-link-de-bot%C3%A3o-de-acordo-com-um-select/206905?noredirect=1#comment423237_206905) , em que o botão de "ADERIR AO PLANO" muda de link de acordo com as opções escolhidas nos select.

Dois dos 4 select que o usuário deve selecionar, são ESTADO e CIDADE, estes, não escritos no option do select e sim são puxados de um banco de dados.

Portanto, para que o botão de aderir troque de link conforme as opções selecionadas, precisava saber o value de cada opção do select, que são puxadas do banco de dados.

Por isso, gostaria de saber se é possível descobrir o value de um select que é puxado do banco de dados, ou se há alguma outra maneira de mencionar a cidade, ou estado sem ser pelo value, que nesse caso não existe.

Obrigado.

```
   jQuery(function($){
        $('#volume, #tipo, #estados').change(function(){
        var volume = $('#volume').val();
        var tipo = $('#tipo').val();
        var estados = $(this).val();

            if (volume == "peq" && tipo == "visitas_quatro" && estados == "SP") {
          $('.Linkbotao').attr('href', 'site.com');
```

Comment: O Exemplo que fiz a baixo é exatamente pra isso

Comment: Certo, só que no meu caso para cada combinação de cidade e estado com as outras opções ele geraria um link. Por exemplo: Estado (SP,) Cidade (São Paulo), Volume (50), Visitas (4) é um link. Já Estado (SC), Cidade (Florianópolis), Volume (100), Visitas (8) é outro link. E assim por diante.
Como irei definir um link para cada cidade com o código que você postou abaixo?
No momento estou fazendo assim: if (volume == "peq" && tipo == "visitas_quatro" && estados == "?" && cidades == "?") {
$('.Linkbotao').attr('href','http://site.com'); aonde tem "?" seria o value de cada option doestado e cidade

Comment: esta fazendo da forma correta, nao esta funcionando?

Comment: Ainda não testei com o código que vc me enviou. Como não tenho muita intimidade com o assunto (js), não estou sabendo qual informação do código que você me passou para colocar ali onde estão as "?", onde seria o value. Você sabe me dizer?

Comment: vou montar, perai

Comment: Editei o codigo da cidade, da uma olhada

Comment: Cara, editei ali minha pergunta e coloquei  o meu código até o momento. (Só a parte que muda o link do botão) To quebrando a cabeça pra tentar entender esse código que você postou, mas não to conseguindo adaptar ele ao meu código. Será que você não consegue pegar esse código que postei como base e me dar um exemplo em cima dele de como seria com o estado SP selecionado e cidade São Paulo, por exemplo. Vi que no seu código ali tem alguma coisa com o país, já na minha tabela seria só o estado e cidade mesmo. De qualquer maneira agradeço a atenção que tens me dado. To quase chegando lá.

Comment: Ve se agora fica melhor, atualizei.

Comment: Cara, ainda ta um pouco complicado pra mim, desculpa rsrs. Eu preciso adicionar aquele function cidade, e function estado? To meio perdido ali com o País no meio, no meu caso seria so estado e cidade, que são puxados do banco, já o tipo e volume estão listados no select, no próprio código. E onde eu indicaria o estado e cidade para um link, por exemplo o de são paulo - sp?

Se puder da uma olhadinha no código fonte da tabela, pra vc ver como eu to fazendo até o momento. O link é: https://piscinafacil.com.br/tabela_teste2.html

Comment: O pais voce pode tirar, ignore ele, foca so no ultimo que é cidade, onde dei o exemplo

Comment: É dos botoes ADERIR que voce quer mudar?

Comment: Isso mesmo, é o link do botão ADERIR. Ele mudaria conforme a combinação de opções que é selecionada nos Selects.

Cada combinação é um preço(plano) e cada preço é um link para adesão.
Você pode perceber que ao selecionar determinada cidade o preço varia, no entanto quando desenvolvemos a tabela, esquecemos que o link do botão iria variar. Ainda não consegui adaptar este código ao meu código

Comment: https://jsbin.com/dokosiq/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Tentei utilizar esse código ali, substituindo o 'select' por '#estados' que é o nome do select da parte de estado. No entanto, quando adicionei o código o select do Estado não está mais mostrando nenhum estado.

Comment: Provavelmente porque você nao implementou da forma correta

Comment: Voce utilizou o let ou var? se foi let, use var (por garantia), da algum erro? eu vi seu codigo pelo link que me passou, e é exatamente o que falei

Comment: Tentei com os dois, let e var. Editei a minha pergunta ali e coloquei o código como está no momento. Juntei a parte do estado com volume e tipo, pois o link mudará de acordo com todas as opções: volume, tipo, estado, e cidade (que nao ta no codigo ainda). Agora, dessa maneira que está ali, está mostrando a lista dos estados, no entanto, quando seleciono as opções que estão descritas ali no código (estado:SP volume:50 e visitas:4) o link não está mudando. O que estou fazendo errado. Se preferir pode olhar direto no código da página: https://piscinafacil.com.br/tabela_teste2.html

Answer (score 0):

É possivel sim. pode fazer assim

```
$(function(){

    // Pais
    function pais(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'funcoes.php',
            data: {
                acao: 'pais'
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);

                for(i = 0; i < data.qtd; i++){

                    $('select[name=pais]').append('<option value="'+data.id[i]+'">'+data.pais[i]+'</option>');
                }
            }
        });
    }
    pais();

    // Estado
    function estado(pais){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'funcoes.php',
            data: {
                acao: 'estado',
                id: pais
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('select[name=estado]').html('<option>Carregando...</option>');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('select[name=estado]').html('');
                $('select[name=estado]').append('<option>Selecione o estado</option>');
                for(i = 0; i < data.qtd; i++){
                    $('select[name=estado]').append('<option value="'+data.id[i]+'">'+data.estado[i]+'</option>');
                }
            }
        });
    }


    // Cidade
    function cidade(estado){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'funcoes.php',
            data: {
                acao: 'cidade',
                id: estado
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('select[name=cidade]').html('<option>Carregando...</option>');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('select[name=cidade]').html('');
                $('select[name=cidade]').append('<option>Selecione a cidade</option>');
                for(i = 0; i < data.qtd; i++){
                    $('select[name=cidade]').append('<option value="'+data.id[i]+'">'+data.cidade[i]+'</option>');
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function verificar(volume, tipo, estados, cidades){
        if(volume == "peq" && tipo == "visitas_quatro" && estados == "?" && cidades == "?"){
            $('.Linkbotao').attr('href', 'google.com');
        }
    }


    $('select[name=pais]').change(function(){
        $('select[name=cidade]').val($("select[name=cidade] option:first-child").val());
        var id = $(this).val();
        estado(id);
    });

    $('select[name=estado]').change(function(){
        var idEstado = $(this).val();
        var cidade = $("select[name=cidade] option:first-child").val();
        var estado = $("select[name=estado] option:first-child").val();
        var tipo = $("select[name=cidade] option:first-child").val();
        var volume = $("select[name=estado] option:first-child").val();

        verificar(volume, tipo, estado, cidade)

        cidade(idEstado);
    });


});
```